# default nature of Indexing for entity fields in Objectify (version 5)

Tags: objectify, google-app-engine

What's the default nature of Indexing for entity fields in Objectify (version 5)?

[Objectify Introduction Page](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Indexing_Embedded_Classes) mentions that all fields are indexed with exceptions.
*By default, all entity fields except Text and Blob are indexed.*

[Best Practices](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices) page mentions that fields are ***not*** indexed by default.
*Objectify does not index anything by default; you must explicitly request it with the @Index annotation. Use it wisely.*

These 2 statements contradict. What's the default Indexing nature for below class? Are the fields indexed?

```
@Entity
class Foo {
   Long id;
   String attributeA;
   String attributeB;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in bold at the top of IntroductionToObjectify, that page documents the obsolete v3 of Objectify. It is an old wiki page preserved for historical reasons.

BestPractices (and every other page not explicitly marked as obsolete) reflects the current (v5) version of Objectify. Fields are *not* indexed by default.

Comment: ah I missed that note in Objectify wiki. Somehow when I started searching for objectify I ended up with obsolete wiki and did not notice it.